# Is a string a char in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char

Can a `char*` in C++ receive a string as a parameter? If so how does this work.

**Example:**

```
myfunc("hello"); //call
myfunc(char * c)
{ ...
}
```

How exactly are chars related to strings?

Comment: Do you mean a c++ `string` ? If so, the answer is no - you need to call str.c_str(); to convert it

Answer (score 2):

The type of the literal `"hello"` is `const char[6]`, that is an array of characters with space for the string and a null terminating byte.

C++ allows for converting a function argument to another type when passing it. In this case the array type gets converted to pointer type, `const char *`, with the pointer referencing the first character with value `'h'`.

C++03 allowed for conversion to `char *`, dropping the `const`, but it was undefined behavior to actually modify the string. This was done for old-school C compatibility and has been revoked in the new C++11 standard, so your example will not pass a newer compiler.

Incidentally, due to legacy considerations inherited from C, it would make no difference if the function were instead declared as `myfunc(char c[6])`. The type of `c` would still be `char *`.

Answer (score -1):

It wont work as expected in your example. Using strings this way (a pointer to the beginning char) only works if the string is null terminated. This is how the old c_str works. If we have a reference to the first char, we can iterate until we find the terminating character, "\0" to access the entire string.

Comment: What does null termination have to do with the *first* character, where is there a non-null terminated string in the example, and what does a newline have to do with anything?

Comment: what does *"\n" to access the entire string* mean?  if it's null terminated, shouldn't you iterate until you find the null?  seems the example should work just fine unless myfunc does something funcy (:p) with the parameter.

Comment: i meant to type \0 as the terminating char

Comment: What does it have to do with the first char? The string is stored in contiguous blocks, so all you need is a pointer to the first char, and to make sure the string is terminated.

Comment: just read dogbert's post for a better explanation.